# Using Bluetooth to create an RFID Tag

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, rfid

I have read several articles that claim that it is not possible to emulate an RFID tag using a cell phone.  I am curious if it is possible to use bluetooth to send out a beacon that is compatible with an existing RFID tag reader.  It is said that RFID tags work on specific frequencies making it impossible to imitate with a cell phone using wifi or bluetooth.  I would like to know if it is possible to write software to turn a cell phone into a passive RFID tag without attaching any new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

RFID and BLE are different protocols requiring different hardware.

No, you can't turn a cellphone into an RFID tag unless it has RFID hardware. BLE hardware is not RFID hardware, and can't be made to act like it, just like you can use your Motorola Walkabout walkie-talkie send and receive ham radio signals.

I believe that the hardware that supports ApplePay is RFID, so if you could gain access to that, you might be able to make your Apple Pay compatible iPhone act like an RFID tag, but Apple keeps that stuff locked down tight, and I might be wrong in my understanding in any case.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about Wifi/Bluetooth and RFID using the same hardware is not possible.

On a smartphone you can achieve this RFID tag emulation using NFC technology if your phone has a NFC chip. Today NFC is mainly about ISO14443 so the target RFID reader must also support this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't confuse RFID and NFC**.  Both technologies evolved from a common base with passive versions of both technologies using radio energy sent by a reader to either a RFID Tag (just a very simple chip containing unique identifiers with an antenna attached) or a NFC device, which sends information back to the reader using the reflected energy.

They use different protocols as @Maxime-C mentions.  Most importantly, the range is quite different, with NFC it is just a few inches, where as with RFID it is several meters or more.  While some RFID readers may also support NFC, I don't believe mobile phones support RFID.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it actually is possible. An RFID tag operates in radio freqs of 125khz to about 14 Mhz while Bluetooth operates at 2483.5 Mhz. The difference in bandwidth of over 2000 Mhz is enough to modulate an imitated signal of an RFID.
The problem however is how good you are in assembly programming. Although Android or linux does not require drivers to drive the Bluetooth hardware, no software/firmware technology currently exists to hammer your phone's Bluetooth adapter to give out a lower frequency by Modulation- or rather, everybody has been lazy enough to just buy a $1 to $5 RFID tag than to use a $250 phone as a convenient replacement.

Comment: P.S. If you have the funds, I'll help you develop it.